# "Not interested" in job listing from Careers 2.0 ad box

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I couldn't find anything about this so perhaps it would make a good feature to add to Careers 2.0.

I'd like to see the ability to mark a job posting/listing as "Not interested" so it won't show up in my search results or from within the ad box.

Does this already exist as a feature or would this be something new?

Comment: I imagine this might be very complex to do - but it would be super cool. It might actually lead to *more* interaction with job listings, because you'd have to open them to reach the check box.

Comment: Perhaps something similar to the thumbs up/down for existing ad feedback. Thumbs up would add it to your favorites and the thumbs down would add it to your "ignore" list.

Comment: I guess the main point here from SEs perspective is that they'll be able to base the jobs a user is shown on that users previously preferred jobs, rather than the tags in the question etc. From a user perspective what might be worrying is that what you're looking for changes over time..